# How to show $f(x) = f(y) + \int\limits_0^1 \nabla f(y + t(x-y))^T(x-y)dt$?

Tags: optimization, proof-explanation, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I am familiar with the following result.

Suppose $f$ is continuously differentiable, then there exists  $t \in (0,1)$
such that
$$f(x)  = f(y) + \nabla f(y + t(x-y))^T(x-y)$$

However, I recently read an [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4980.pdf) (`Page 267` of Text, `Page 40` of PDF) whereby the author seemingly used the following result,

$$f(x)  = f(y) + \int\limits_0^1 \nabla f(y + t(x-y))^T(x-y)dt$$

> [image]

It is not apparently how
$$\int\limits_0^1 \nabla f(y + t(x-y))^T(x-y)dt = \nabla f(y + t(x-y))^T(x-y)$$

Does anyone know how to show $f(x)  = f(y) + \int\limits_0^1 \nabla f(y + t(x-y))^T(x-y)dt$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $g(t) = f(y + t(x-y))$. Then by the chain rule, $g'(t) = \nabla f(y + t(x-y))^\top (x-y)$.
The statement is simply the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$g(1) - g(0) = \int_0^1 g'(t) \, dt.$$

---

The other result is the mean value theorem: there exists $t \in (0,1)$ such that
$$\frac{g(1) - g(0)}{1-0} = g'(t).$$

Comment: Ok I see. I probably should not have used the same $t$ for these results.